# If $|I|$ < $|J|$ and $(F_i)_{i \in I}$ are finite sets, is $|\cup_{i \in I}F_i| < |J|$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $I, J$ be two infinite sets with $|I| < |J|$, and let  $(F_i)_{i \in I}$ be a collection of finite sets whose union is

$$
K := \bigcup_{i \in I}F_i
$$

If $s := \sup_i|F_i|$ is finite, we can give a straighforward bound for $|K|$ as follows,

$$
|K| = \left|\bigcup_{i \in I}F_i\right| \leq \left|\bigcup_{i \in I} \ \{1, \dots, s\} \times \{i\}\right| \leq |I^s| \leq |I|^s = |I| < |J|
$$

My question is the following: does $|K| < |J|$ hold even when the sizes of the finite sets are unbounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and it follows from that fact that if $I,J$ are infinite and $F_i$ is at most countable for all $i \in I$. Then
$$
\operatorname{card} \left(\bigcup_{i \in I} F_i \right) \le \operatorname{card} \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} \{i\} \times \mathbb N \right) = \operatorname{card}(I \times \mathbb N) = \operatorname{card}(I)
$$ 
I'm using the axiom of choice here (in a couple of places, actually). It might be a worthwhile exercise to spot all the places the axiom of choice is used in this argument.

Comment: Great answer! One follow-up question though, since my cardinal arithmetic is a bit rusty: the last equality (assuming AC) follows from the fact that if $d \leq e$ are infinite cardinals then $d \cdot e = e$, right?

Comment: @GuidoA. That's right.

Comment: Great. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @GuidoA. You're most welcome!

Comment: How do you prove $|\bigcup_{i\in I}F_i|\le|I\times\mathbb N|$ without choice?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo In my post I demand, in the absence of choice, the existence of $(f_i \mid i \in I)$ such that $f_i \colon F_i \to \mathbb N$ is an injection. Now I realize that I also implicitly assumed the $F_i$ to be disjoint (or alternatively $I$ to be wellordered). Since I want to define $x \to (i,f_i(x))$ as my injection. Since OP seemingly isn't interested in the $\mathrm{ZF} + \neg \mathrm{C}$ result anyway, I'll remove that to streamline my answer. Thanks for spotting the mistake!